# how to start amcharts in v5 from left

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts5

hello in this example which I leave the link below you can see that the XY chart of amChart 5 is starting from left to right
and I want it to start from right to left  I could find some ways on amchart v4 but in this version, since it is v5, I couldn't.
I'll appreciate your answers
[you can check out the example in here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/bars-with-moving-bullets/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add two settings and modify one...

### `yRenderer`

```js
let yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
  opposite: true // add this
});
```

### `yAxis`

```js
let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "name",
    renderer: yRenderer,
    paddingLeft: 40 // instead of paddingRight
  })
);
```

### `xRenderer`

```js
let xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
  inversed: true // add this
});
```

---

*Below you will find the example given in amCharts documentation. I did not change anything, except these little extra settings.*

```js
// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
  am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);

let data = [
  {
    name: "Monica",
    steps: 45688,
    pictureSettings: {
      src: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/monica.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Joey",
    steps: 35781,
    pictureSettings: {
      src: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/joey.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Ross",
    steps: 25464,
    pictureSettings: {
      src: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/ross.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Phoebe",
    steps: 18788,
    pictureSettings: {
      src: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/phoebe.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Rachel",
    steps: 15465,
    pictureSettings: {
      src: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/rachel.jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Chandler",
    steps: 11561,
    pictureSettings: {
      src: "https://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/chandler.jpg"
    }
  }
];

// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
let chart = root.container.children.push(
  am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    wheelX: "none",
    wheelY: "none",
    paddingLeft: 50,
    paddingRight: 40
  })
);

// Create axes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/

let yRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
  opposite: true
});
yRenderer.grid.template.set("visible", false);

let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "name",
    renderer: yRenderer,
    paddingLeft: 40
  })
);

let xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
  inversed: true
});
xRenderer.grid.template.set("strokeDasharray", [3]);

let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    min: 0,
    renderer: xRenderer
  })
);

// Add series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
let series = chart.series.push(
  am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Income",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueXField: "steps",
    categoryYField: "name",
    sequencedInterpolation: true,
    calculateAggregates: true,
    maskBullets: false,
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      dy: -30,
      pointerOrientation: "vertical",
      labelText: "{valueX}"
    })
  })
);

series.columns.template.setAll({
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  cornerRadiusBR: 10,
  cornerRadiusTR: 10,
  cornerRadiusBL: 10,
  cornerRadiusTL: 10,
  maxHeight: 50,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
});

let currentlyHovered;

series.columns.template.events.on("pointerover", function(e) {
  handleHover(e.target.dataItem);
});

series.columns.template.events.on("pointerout", function(e) {
  handleOut();
});

function handleHover(dataItem) {
  if (dataItem && currentlyHovered != dataItem) {
    handleOut();
    currentlyHovered = dataItem;
    let bullet = dataItem.bullets[0];
    bullet.animate({
      key: "locationX",
      to: 1,
      duration: 600,
      easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
    });
  }
}

function handleOut() {
  if (currentlyHovered) {
    let bullet = currentlyHovered.bullets[0];
    bullet.animate({
      key: "locationX",
      to: 0,
      duration: 600,
      easing: am5.ease.out(am5.ease.cubic)
    });
  }
}


let circleTemplate = am5.Template.new({});

series.bullets.push(function(root, series, dataItem) {
  let bulletContainer = am5.Container.new(root, {});
  let circle = bulletContainer.children.push(
    am5.Circle.new(
      root,
      {
        radius: 34
      },
      circleTemplate
    )
  );

  let maskCircle = bulletContainer.children.push(
    am5.Circle.new(root, { radius: 27 })
  );

  // only containers can be masked, so we add image to another container
  let imageContainer = bulletContainer.children.push(
    am5.Container.new(root, {
      mask: maskCircle
    })
  );

  // not working
  let image = imageContainer.children.push(
    am5.Picture.new(root, {
      templateField: "pictureSettings",
      centerX: am5.p50,
      centerY: am5.p50,
      width: 60,
      height: 60
    })
  );

  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    locationX: 0,
    sprite: bulletContainer
  });
});

// heatrule
series.set("heatRules", [
  {
    dataField: "valueX",
    min: am5.color(0xe5dc36),
    max: am5.color(0x5faa46),
    target: series.columns.template,
    key: "fill"
  },
  {
    dataField: "valueX",
    min: am5.color(0xe5dc36),
    max: am5.color(0x5faa46),
    target: circleTemplate,
    key: "fill"
  }
]);

series.data.setAll(data);
yAxis.data.setAll(data);

let cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}));
cursor.lineX.set("visible", false);
cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);

cursor.events.on("cursormoved", function() {
  let dataItem = series.get("tooltip").dataItem;
  if (dataItem) {
    handleHover(dataItem)
  }
  else {
    handleOut();
  }
})

// Make stuff animate on load
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
series.appear();
chart.appear(1000, 100);
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```